# All nonempty open subsets of a nonempty open set intersect

Tags: general-topology

Consider a topology $(P, Opens)$ and write $Opens_{\neq\varnothing}$ for the set of nonempty open sets.

Call a nonempty open set $O\in Opens_{\neq\varnothing}$ **tangled** when all of its nonempty open sets intersect.  In symbols:
$$
O\text{ is tangled}
\quad\text{when}\quad
\forall O',O''\in Opens_{\neq\varnothing}. O',O''\subseteq O \Rightarrow O'\cap O''\neq\varnothing .
$$

**Question:** Can anyone provide a reference for where such a property may have been studied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [hyperconencted spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space)   will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to A. Ekbote for this reference to *Hyperconnected spaces*:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space

An open set is tangled in my sense above if and only if it is a hyperconnected subspace of the topology.